# stack function only stacks the last raster file

Tags: r, r-raster

I am trying to create a  raster stack of 120 raster files. I am generating these files inside a loop and adding the generated raster to a rasterstack. The code looks like:

```
library(raster)
stack_P_95 <- stack()
for (i in startyear:endyear)
{
file <- paste(indir,"\\prec_",i,".nc",sep="")
command <- paste("cdo timmin ",file," ",workdir,"min.nc",sep="")
system(command)
command <- paste("cdo timmax ",file," ",workdir,"max.nc",sep="")
system(command)
command <- paste("cdo timpctl,95 ",file," ",workdir,"min.nc 
",workdir,"max.nc ",workdir,"P95_",i,".nc",sep="")
system(command)
grid <- raster(paste(workdir,"P95_",i,".nc",sep=""))
stack_P_95 <- stack(stack_P_95,grid)
}  
crs(stack_P_95) <- "+proj=utm +zone=45 +ellps=WGS84 +datum=WGS84 +units=m 
+no_defs" 
writeRaster(stack_P_95,paste(outdir,model,"_P95.nc",sep=""),format="CDF",overwrite=T)
```

But the stack_P_95 that I am creating just has the last raster repeated n(endyear -startyear) times.

what could be the possible reason for this problem??
There are no errors or warnings generated during this process.

I have added the link with my input files and the final outputs: 
[Input files](https://www.dropbox.com/sh/i56gxuar68tqtlz/AACHRHzu07M2VvN2fN-G-HuGa?dl=0)

Comment: Could you add a reproducible example. For example there is no function called `addLayer` in `base` R.

Comment: Works for me. Are you sure your data files aren't all identical?

Comment: Here's code to create a test set of raster files containing a grid of year numbers in the current directory: `r=raster();for(i in 2001:2004){r[]=i;writeRaster(r,paste0("temp_",i,".nc"))}` #WARNING MAY OVERWRITE YOUR FILES# Doing that, then running your code, I get a 4-layer stack with the four year values in the layers. ie it works for me.

Comment: @Spacedman The files are not identical. I tried plotting the "tempnc" file each time the loops run and all of the images are different.

Comment: Edit your question to show some code that shows how you demonstrate to yourself that the output stack is just the same repeated raster stacked.

Comment: When I run your code with your data from 1981 to 1985 I get a `stack_P_95` with five layers that are clearly different. I don't know what the `stack_1` you reference in "But the stack_1 that I am creating..." is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's nothing wrong with your code.

Create some example rasters:

```
> library(raster)
Loading required package: sp
> for(i in 2001:2005){ r = raster(matrix(i,10,10)); writeRaster(r,paste0("temp_",i,".nc"))}
Loading required namespace: ncdf4
```

That gives me:

```
$ ls
temp_2001.nc  temp_2002.nc  temp_2003.nc  temp_2004.nc  temp_2005.nc
```

All of which are different:

```
$ gdalinfo temp_2004.nc | grep max
  layer#max=2004
    max=2004
$ gdalinfo temp_2001.nc | grep max
  layer#max=2001
    max=2001
```

Now *in a clean R session* I run your code:

```
 library(raster)
 workdir="./"
 stack_1 <- stack()
 startyear = 2001
 endyear = 2004
 for (i in startyear:endyear)
 {
 tempnc <- raster(paste(workdir,"temp_",i,".nc",sep=""))
 stack_1 <- stack(stack_1,tempnc)
 }
```

And I get a stack with four different layers:

```
> range(stack_1[[1]][])
[1] 2001 2001
> range(stack_1[[2]][])
[1] 2002 2002
> range(stack_1[[3]][])
[1] 2003 2003
```

Unlike your code, my code is fully reproducible. If you run my code in a clean R environment and all the layers are "2004" then something is horribly wrong with your system. If the layers are the same as mine then there's something wrong with your files or the code you aren't showing us.

Comment: I have added my whole code as well as my input files and output files in to the question. I am using the output from one operation and reading it back into the stack which is not working in my case.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code

```
r <- list()  # create list objects

for (i in startyear:endyear)
{
r[i] <- raster(paste(workdir,"temp_",i,".nc",sep=""))
}

rs <- stack(r) # create raster stack from list object
```

Comment: If I first generate the output then list them as you suggest, stacking works. But I don't understand why the stacking does not work within the loop.